# How to implement to a generic protocol, which has a function using the Type of associatedtype?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am creating some class confirms to a generic protocol, this generic protocol has a method which accept a parameter of the Type of the `associatedtype`, I use Xcode to generate the stub for me:

```
import UIKit

struct SomeObject: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
}

protocol INetworkManager {
    associatedtype ResponseObject
    func get(url: String, ofType: ResponseObject.Type, completion: (ResponseObject?, Error?) -> Void)
}

class NetworkManager: INetworkManager {
    typealias ResponseObject = Codable

    func get(url: String, ofType: ResponseObject.Protocol, completion: (ResponseObject?, Error?) -> Void) {
        completion(SomeObject(id: "1", name: "hello"), nil)
    }
}
```

Instead of `ResponseObject.Type` it generates `ResponseObject.Protocol` for me, I don't actually know what this `ResponseObject.Protocol` is, and I can not pass `SomeObject.self` as the parameter like this:

```
let networkManager = NetworkManager()
networkManager.get(url: "http://whatever.com", ofType: SomeObject.self) { (responseObject, error) in
    print("got response object named: \(responseObject.name)")
}
```

compiler gave me this error:

```
error: Cannot convert value of type 'SomeObject.Type' to expected argument type 'NetworkManager.ResponseObject.Protocol' (aka '(Decodable & Encodable).Protocol')
```

I think something wrong with my implementation, anyone can give me any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please can you fix the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your class doesn't conform to the protocol.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? When you have an `associatedtype` on `protocol` then passing it as a function argument is unnecessary. You can directly use `MyType.self` in the method.

Comment: @JeremyP Sorry for my mistake, the code snippet above has been fixed now.

Comment: @Kamaran Actually, I want write a generic protocol for my `NetworkManager`, which has a `get` method accept a `Codable` class. I have update the above snippet to show what I want to achieve, please take a look, thanks.

Comment: Passing types around in Swift is a Bad Smell. You just about never need to do it. Rethink this.

Comment: @matt I need the `get` method to return an object of that `Type`, and this `Type` varies among different API endpoints, what should I do besides passing the types around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't how associated types work. `get` should be generic over its response type, but the network manager itself isn't generic over some specific response type. I believe what you meant to here is this:

```
protocol NetworkManager {
    func get<ResponseObject>(url: String, 
                             ofType: ResponseObject.Type, 
                             completion: (Result<ResponseObject, Error>) -> Void) 
    where ResponseObject: Decodable
}

class TrivialNetworkManager: NetworkManager {
    func get<ResponseObject>(url: String, 
                             ofType: ResponseObject.Type, 
                             completion: (Result<ResponseObject, Error>) -> Void) 
    where ResponseObject: Decodable {
        completion(.success(SomeObject(id: "1", name: "hello"))
    }
}
```

For a more worked-out version of this specific problem you can read my [protocol series](http://robnapier.net/start-with-a-protocol), but the important concept here is that NetworkManager doesn't vary over its ResponseType, so there's no reason to make its ResponseType an associated type.

What you wrote is trying to say "some network managers will have a Codable ResponseType, and other network managers will have some other kind of ResponseType." Not "some other specific response type (like User)" but "some other protocol that its response types would have to conform to." While it's conceivable to build something like that, it's much more complex, and you'd need to explain your precise use case in order to design it. Specifically, you'd need to show several concrete implementations of your protocol in order to see what kind of shared code you're trying to extract.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for your detailed answer! I should have miss used the `associatedtype` which meant to be varied among different concrete classes, and is not for this use case. I will change my code to use generic method in protocol instead.